# ЯП в которых нет различия между кодом и данными

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

В каких языках программирования нет большого различия между кодом программы и данными, с которыми этот код работает? Т.е. программа может работать с кодом как с данными и наоборот.

Comment: Традиционно - lisp.

Comment: а ассемблер? я бы и сам поискал но непонятно по каким фичам языка отбирать: наличие eval, еще что то?

Comment: Речь не просто о динамических языках?..

Comment: о любых языках программирования

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все семейство Lisp (Common Lisp, Scheme и другие), [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/), [REBOL](http://www.rebol.com/), Forth, [Factor](http://factorcode.org/), [Io](http://iolanguage.org/)

Comment: REBOL-Factor-Io не знаю, а вот что касается tcl & forth -- странное утверждение.

Comment: Ну и почему?

Comment: Хорошо, Forth может и спорно, но вот Tcl?

Comment: А как в Tcl получить доступ к своему коду? Скомпоновать в виде программы  и выполнить данные (через eval) это пожалуйста.

Про все остальное (кроме Lisp) ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: Дык это везде так. Везде выполняются данные через eval, просто в Lisp это список, в Tcl это строчка. Вот и вся разница.

Comment: Io вполне подходит, не понял сомнений зачем его убрали из списка.

Comment: Вообще да. Там нельзя взять и зацитировать код, можно только что-то делать с лениво выполняющимися аргументами.

Answer (score 2):

Все [homoiconic](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) языки:

- Lisp-семейство : списки
- SmallTalk : объекты
- <скажите как называется ?> : деревья

Comment: я так понял понятие "код как данные" оказалось шире и касается не только гомоиконности https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_as_data

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, речь идет о рефлексии? Соответствующие средства имеются в JavaScript, SmallTalk, Python, Ruby. Средства анализа типов также есть и в C#

Comment: в ассемблере

> Нет различия между данными (то есть буквой) и кодом программы (то есть командами). Данные процессор не станет выполнять, только если получит специальный код перепрыгнуть через них или код прекратить программу вообще

[источник][1]

причем здесь рефлексия?


  [1]: http://bitfry.narod.ru/01.htm

Comment: рефлексия при том, что она позволяет обращаться к коду, как к данным и получать метаданные о типах

Comment: рефлексия по большей части read/only, речь скорее о полноценном метапрограммировании -- например добавление произвольных синтаксических конструкций, в базовом языке отсутствующих, оптимизация исходного кода, автогенерация кода (типа пишешь в исходнике BNF bla | bla bla* , получаешь кусок кода, потом засовываешь его куда-нибудь в общую кучу проекта, и запускаешь макрос-спецификатор который под твою целевую платформу код соптимизирует, или дернет LLVM который тебе его в память скомпилит и слинкует с работающим интерпретатором в рантайме